# The Natural Isomorphism in Yoneda Lemma

Tags: category-theory, yoneda-lemma

$\DeclareMathOperator{\sets}{\textbf{Sets}}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{\nat}{Nat}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{\hom}{Hom}$
I am trying to understand the Yoneda lemma from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoneda_lemma) and I am stuck at one point.

Let $C$ be a category and $F$ be a functor $F:C\to \sets$. Then for each object $A$ in $C$, there is a bijection
$$\nat(\hom(A, -), F)\cong F(A)$$

**But then** the wiki article states that "Moreover, this isomorphism in natural in $A$ and $F$ when both sides are regarded as functors from $\sets^C\times C$ to $\sets$".
(Here $\sets^C$ denotes the category of functors from $C$ to $\sets$.)

I am unable to see how to view $\nat(\hom(A, -), F)$ and $F(A)$ as functors $\sets^C\times C\to \sets$. Can somebody

Can somebody please spell this out a little bit. Thank you.

Comment: On objects the first functor is defined by $(F,A) \mapsto \text{Nat}(\text{Hom}(A,-),F)$ while the second is defined by $(F,A) \mapsto F(A)$. On morphisms the first functor is defined by $((\alpha,f):(F,A)\to (F',A')) \mapsto (\theta \mapsto (\alpha \cdot \theta \cdot  \text{Hom}(f,-)))$ while the second is defined by $((\alpha,f):(F,A)\to (F',A')) \mapsto (x \mapsto \alpha_{A'}(F(f)(x)))$

Comment: JIC... if we considered the case where $f : X \to Y$ denotes a function between sets and $x$ denotes an element of $X$, can you see how the expression $f(x)$ can be regarded as (the evaluation of) a function $Y^X \times X \to Y$?

Comment: I had this same question, thank you!

Comment: Thank you, @Nex , I found your answer most helpful.  If I understood correctly, the morphism $(\alpha , f): (F,A)\rightarrow (F',A')$ gets mapped to the set function which takes $x \in F(A)$ to $\alpha_{A'}(F(f)(x)) \in F'(A')$.  And that set function is based on the natural transformation $\alpha$ and could also be written as $x \mapsto F'(f)(\alpha_A(x))$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's fix some notation. For convenience let's denote Hom$(A,-)$ by just $A^\wedge$. For clarity, if $\mathcal{D}$ is any category and $X,Y \in \mathcal{D}$ then denote the Hom-set from $X$ to $Y$ by $\mathcal{D}(X,Y)$.

With these conventions $$\mathrm{Nat}(\mathrm{Hom}(A,−),F) \cong F(A)$$ becomes 
$$\mathrm{Set}^\mathcal{C}(A^\wedge,F) \cong F(A).$$

An object of $\mathrm{Set}^\mathcal{C}$ is a functor $\mathcal{C} \to \mathrm{Set}$ and morphisms are natural transformations.

If we want to view this isomorphism as a natural transformation then we should first specify its source and target functors.

Its source is the composition 
$$ \mathcal{C} \times\mathrm{Set}^\mathcal{C} \overset{Y \times 1} \longrightarrow (\mathrm{Set}^\mathcal{C})^{op} \times \mathrm{Set}^\mathcal{C} \overset{\mathrm{Hom}} \longrightarrow \mathrm{Set}, \;\;\;\;\;\; (A,F) \mapsto \mathrm{Set}^\mathcal{C}(A^\wedge,F)$$
where $Y$ is the (contravariant) Yoneda-embedding $A \mapsto A^\wedge$. 
The target functor is just the evaluation functor $(F,A) \mapsto F(A)$.
On morphisms (= pairs of morphisms in $\mathcal{C}$ and morphisms in $\mathrm{Set}^\mathcal{C}$) they are defined accordingly.

These two functors themselves both have source $\mathcal{C}\times \mathrm{Set}^\mathcal{C}$ and target Set.

tl;dr It should be $\mathcal{C}\times \mathrm{Set}^\mathcal{C}$ instead of $\mathrm{Set}^\mathcal{C} \times \mathcal{C}$.